# iCloud Photo Library with React Native RCTCameraRoll

Tags: react-native

I'm using react-native 0.51 and was hoping to provide iOS users of my app with access to the camera roll with including content stored on iCloud Photo Library (i.e. only thumbnails stored locally), as in the native iOS Photos app.

The documentation is thin, but I would expect that this is commonly needed functionality.  However, when I run:

```
 CameraRoll.getPhotos({
   first: 100,
   assetType: 'All',
 })
```

I'm returned a single page of results (many fewer than my photo library), with `page_info.has_next_page == false`.  Interestingly all of the image records provided have an `isStored` attribute (and always `true`).

Is iCloud Photo Library supported in RCTCameraRoll currently?  If not, are there any alternatives that you're having good experiences with?

Ideally, Android support would be available in the same library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Examining the source code for the library (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Libraries/CameraRoll), one can see that with the exception of RCTPhotoLibraryImageLoader, the library is written with the deprecated AssetsLibrary API (since iOS 9) that predates modern iCloud enabled photo libraries.  RCTPhotoLibraryImageLoader was updated to the modern Photos API (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos?language=objc) to to allow for downloads of cloud-stored URIs, but `getPhotos` doesn't seem to be able to return them or does so inconsistently (when I call `getPhotos` with `groupTypes:'All'`, some results seem to be references to *some* remotely cached content, but the majority of my iCloud-stored photos don't appear at all).

One alternative is react-native-photos-framework, an iOS-only Photos API can be found here:
https://github.com/olofd/react-native-photos-framework

Another alternative that might work for some is a component which is a wrapper around native image picker and camera objects:
https://github.com/react-community/react-native-image-picker
This is relatively rigid (no multi-select, limited control over appearance), but in exchange, some of the tricky details of are handled for you, e.g. downloading iCloud content is handled.